# Adding SQL Server Data Tools 2012 to my Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have installed SQL Server Data Tools 2012 but don't know how to integrate it into Visual Studio 2013 that I installed before. The problem is that when opening Visual Studio for the first time after installation I have chosen the option "General" instead of "BI" which refers to business intelligence and that was by mistake :(

Now I want to reconfigure Visual Studio to be able to work with BI tools but don't find a way to do it. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can not use VS 2013 with SSDT 2012.  You have to use either VS 2010 or VS 2012.  VS 2010 shell is installed by default with SQL 2012 but it is no longer supported and they currently only update the VS 2012 tools so go ahead and update to VS 2012.

This has been the way with BIDS and SSDT since SQL2005.  If you want to develop for more than one SQL Server version you have always had to keep more than one version of VS installed.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/03/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx